# Wake On Lan (WOL) iMac 2009 El Capitan, Sierra, not working

Tags: macos, ethernet, wake-on-lan

System:

- iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2009)
- El Capitan 10.11.6
- Non-Apple modem/router

Wake on LAN isn’t working. I have tried a variety of methods: iOS apps (Fing, iNet, Mocha); Mac applications and scripting on another Mac (WakeOnMac, wakeonlan perl script).

Yes, I’m on a local network, and yes I’ve ticked the ‘Wake for network access’ in System Preferences. Also checked with `pmset -g` that womp = 1. I have also tried overriding `networkoversleep` (1).

I initially believed the Ethernet (which directly connects the iMac to the router and should make this process more reliable) disconnected during sleep. I tested this by opening System Preferences > Network and leaving that open while I sleep it. When I woke it from sleep, the Network Preferences panel was still open (obviously) and Ethernet (at the top) showed as Disconnected and features a red dot beside it. It reconnects very quickly, but that’s no good for WOL.

I have now tested installs of Mavericks, Yosemite and macOS Sierra on a separate partition. Mavericks and Yosemite both allowed WOL (despite the Ethernet 'disconnecting' issue still being there, suggesting it doesn't actually disconnect). macOS Sierra, as El Capitan, does not allow WOL. The `pmset` settings and 'Wake for network access' etc. are all the same.

Does anybody know of an obscure network setting somewhere that disables WOL despite it being enabled in `pmset`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on an early '09 Mac mini that I just upgraded from Mavericks to El Capitan. WOL over ethernet worked fine on 10.9, but nothing I've tried has worked on 10.11. For what it's worth, I see in Wireshark that the magic packets are still reaching my mini when it is awake.

Comment: Incidentally, I was never able to get WOL working over wifi on the mini but ethernet worked reliably. Also, I don't even have a router between my mini and the computer that's trying to do the waking.

Comment: I found this link: https://ptarmiganlabs.com/blog/2015/07/13/wake-on-lan-workaround-for-osx-yosemite-on-mac-mini/
which suggested using a USB ethernet adaptor. I have an adaptor lying around, and it indeed seems to work on El Capitan! Seems crazy that a cheap 3rd party adaptor works but the built-in interface won't. Hopefully someone else can find a solution not requiring an adaptor.

Comment: FYI, the generic adaptor I'm using is: https://www.amazon.com/Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Adapter-1000Mbps/dp/B00N8RB7JK
which works fine on OS X after installing a driver.

Comment: @JulianPanetta: Interesting about the dongle, suggesting the network card itself (or OS X's management of it?) is toasted. I notice the USB 2 version is 10/100 whereas the USB 3 is 10/100/1000. Is yours USB 3, do you have a USB 2 or 3 port on the Mini, and (if USB 2) does it limit speeds back down to 10/100?

Comment: My adapter is the gigabit USB 3, but my mini only has USB 2. I just tested it: I get 310Mbits/sec up and 340Mbits/sec down--so definitely still better than 10/100.

Comment: @JulianPanetta: Thanks for checking. I'm about to test Yosemite's implementation of WOL and will edit the main answer with the result. I will probably stick to the most recent OS that supports it but will certainly remember your recommendation for the future, as I may change my mind :-) (and it's good for others to see).

Comment: Wake on LAN (Wireless) is not working for me on a MBP running El Capitan OS X 10.11.6 (15G1421). My expectation is that the screen should 'start' i.e. present the login screen if I send a WOL message. Is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. But you should hear the drive spin up (if it's HDD) and be able to access other services, e.g. iOS Remote app should be able to access iTunes library if iTunes is running on the MBP.

Answer (score -1):

Wake on Lan only works if the Mac is sleeping. You cannot wake up a Mac that has been shutdown no matter what third party apps you have. Mac's are not designed to Wake-up from LAN when shutdown for security reasons.

Comment: Please note that title says it all ".....From Sleep...." http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/14/wake-on-lan-mac-iphone/